# Android - Create basic navigation app

Tags: android, navigation

here's what I want to achieve[image]

I want that for each country I click I will be redirected to a page (Each page is an activity right?) that will contain details about the country, like a profile about it.

From each profile there will be a "go back" button, which is showed in the image above.

My question is what strucutre do I use to implement this bottom action bar and the list.

If you can direct me to tutorials with source code that would be awesome.

Thanks very much for your help,
Dvir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom action bar ??? , well there is not action bar as of image you provided, that is basic android specific navigation buttons **handled by android itself**.

**Leftmost** is back which pops out current activity from stack,

**middle** is use to send your application in background and show Home screen,

and **rightmost** to display all apps currently working in multi-tasking mode..

As far as your list is concern you can implement using [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)..

Here is a sample to [implement ListView](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/)..

Hope this helps.....